# check all upper checkboxes(parent and chileds) in tree when i check any child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hye all,
i have a tree of checkboxes with parent child relationship. i just need help that when i check any node of tree, should checked all upper nodes
for example:
  A B C D E are tree nodes. B & C are child of A, E is child of D
so, when i select D or E it should select A B C D

here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>

<title> Checkboxes</title>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
              $(this).closest('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
 }
 });
});
</script>
```

```
<body>

<div id="page-wrap">
   <h1>Checkboxes</h1>  
 <ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tall" id="tall">
        <label for="tall">A</label>
        <ul>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox"  >
                 <label for="tall-1">B</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" >
                 <label for="tall-2">C</label>
                 </ul>
        </ul>
        <ul>
                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox">
                         <label for="tall-2-1">D</label>
                     <ul>   

                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox">
                         <label for="tall-2-2">E</label>
                     </li>
        </ul>

</div>

 </body>

 </html>
```